# How to write to a file a regular expression match

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have been parsing a log file and working on it just using print. I've got it working but I can't figure out how to write it to a file instead of printing it to screen.

I've tried opening output file o for writing, then the following regex

```
matched = re.search(r"(http|https)://(.*?)./+", line)
o.write(matched)
```

It throws an error that it has to be a string object for the .write argument. I've also tried `o.write(matched(1),line)` but that only gets me http. I'm a newbie so I'm sorry if this is to simple a question. But I don't know enough about this to know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the [documentation for Match objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) where one of the functions mentions what you want:

> ```
> Match.group([group1, ...])
> ```
>
> Returns one or more subgroups of the match. If there is a single argument, the result is a single string; if there are multiple arguments, the result is a tuple with one item per argument. Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero (**the whole match is returned**). [...]

Here's a runnable example:

```
import re
line = "Some text with https://www.example.com/ in it"
matched = re.search(r"(http|https)://(.*?)./+", line)
with open("file.txt", "w") as o:
  o.write(matched.group())
```

which results in:

```
$ python3 test.py; cat file.txt; echo
https://www.example.com/
$ python2 test.py; cat file.txt; echo
https://www.example.com/
```

Comment: That documentation helps, but it doesn't discuss writing to a file. I get exactly what I want to print to the screen, but can't write it to a file.

Comment: Ok, I changed the example to write to a file instead. As long as you have a string instead of a Match object, it doesn't really matter where you write it